# Trilogy in which people have reverted to the barbarian ways, with scientists that overlook them

Tags: story-identification

There has been a nuclear war. There are now two sets of people: the barbarians and the scientists. The barbarians are distinguised by the type of weapons they are masters of, the rope/sword/short sticks etc. In the barbarian culture, they fight in a circle to sort out disagreements and arguments.

In one of the later books they are assaulting a mountain containing the scientists.

This is all I can remember.

Comment: We need to wait for an accepted answer for the other one, I think.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[*Battle Circle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Circle) by Piers Anthony, a trilogy consisting of *Sos the Rope*, *Var the Stick*, and *Neq the Sword*.

> Wandering tribes of primitive humans meet and fight and love and die.
>   When one tribe meets another, individuals fight inside a Battle
>   Circle. The loser must become a member of the victorious tribe. Each
>   warrior is named by his weapon. When Sol the Sword is bested by Sol of
>   All Weapons, he loses his tribe, his name, and his weapon. Re-named
>   Sos the Rope, he joins with Sol of All Weapons to try to create
>   something greater than a world of Battle Circles

[image]