# old fantasy book about a barbarian with swords in place of his hands

Tags: story-identification

I don't recall alot of details, except that it was world where fighting was very ritualized, and only done at certain buildings or waystations and with certain rules. The sword hand guy starts to create a society based around fighting. Slowly defeating other groups and growing his group.
I THINK it was both hands that got chopped off and replaced with swords or a sword/dagger combo.
Would have been 70s or 80's I guess. Maybe older. Any help appreciated. Google no help at all.

Comment: semi-duplicate (same series) of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76672/trilogy-in-which-people-have-reverted-to-the-barbarian-ways-with-scientists-tha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the third book of the [Battle Circle trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Circle) by Piers Anthony, Neq the Sword. The hero, Neq, is captured and has his hands cut off but he later has them replaced with sword blades. From chapter eight:

> He woke at dusk. His arms terminated in great crude bandages, -hurting ferociously. Neqa lay beside him, pale and cold. His bracelet was still on her wrist.
>
> ...
>
> When Neq emerged from the intermittent haze of drugs and pain, his right arm terminated in a fixed full-length sword. His left had dull pincers that he could open and close with some discomfort by flexing wrong-seeming muscles.

Comment: Battle Circle! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great books ... read them as a teen. +1 for the great, concise answer :D